# Are rings in algebraic topology generally assumed commutative?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

There's not much to add to the question statement. I know that in algebraic geometry and commutative algebra, one generally works with commutative rings, but I'm unsure if the same holds in algebraic topology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see someone take cohomology with coefficients in a ring that ring is always commutative (and usually either $\mathbb{Z}$ or a field); it doesn't really help in any way to take it to be noncommutative. On the other hand, cohomology rings themselves are [graded-commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded-commutative_ring) rather than commutative on the nose, meaning the product satisfies

$$xy = (-1)^{|x| |y|} yx$$

if $x, y$ are homogeneous and $|x|, |y|$ denotes their degrees. This means they commute unless they are both odd in which case they anticommute. There are good reasons for this but it's a long story.

Noncommutative rings do occasionally show up, e.g. for various purposes one considers the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$ of a fundamental group (as in [L-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-theory)), but I think it will generally be clear when this is happening.

Comment: Well, sometimes you consider cohomology with coefficients in a graded-commutative ring (for instance, in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence).

Answer (score 1):

The [cohomology ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_ring) is (only) [skew-commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded-commutative_ring).

Comment: Real mathematicians work in characteristic $2$, anyway...